# jQuery AJAX Request returning HTML instead of JSON Result (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble extracting data from an AJAX request in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.

Ajax Request Code (contained in a `<script>` block on a razor pages .cshtml page:

```
$("body").ready(function AjaxTest() {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: '/Menus/Admin_MainMenu?action=TestMethod',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Request Successful" + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Request Failed");
        }
    });
})
```

And the corresponding PageModel method (just as test at the moment):

```
[HttpGet]
public string TestMethod()
{
    string mystring = "success";
    return mystring;
}
```

I know the request works, as I get the alert "Request Successful". However, instead of "Request Successful" being followed by my value of `mystring`, I get a string of HTML corresponding to the layout of the .cshtml page.

I've tried changing the data type to JSON (both in the AJAX request using `dataType`, and in the method return type (`jsonrequest`), but that makes the request fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when using `dataType: 'text'` is that the string may rendered as HTML output instead of simple string. Also declaring `function AjaxTest()` inside `ready` event is not a proper way to declare function inside AJAX callback, even the syntax is valid because of scoping issue.

You need to use `JsonResult` return type instead of `string`:

```
public JsonResult OnGetTestMethod()
{
    string mystring = "success";
    return new JsonResult(mystring);
}
```

Then use `handler` parameter inside AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Menus/Admin_MainMenu?handler=TestMethod',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Request Successful " + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Request Failed");
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:**

1) The `JsonResult` mentioned here is not [`System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), it uses [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and doesn't have `JsonRequestBehavior` property.

2) Razor pages uses `OnGet` and `OnPost` action method prefixes to deal with HTTP GET and POST respectively, hence the `[HttpGet]` attribute is unnecessary.

Further references:

[Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

[ASP.NET Core Razor Pages: How to implement AJAX requests](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/)